# Login Page Step Disabled, But Rest Of The Tests Still Run in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am running a simple login and logout test in JMeter for our application.
I have disabled some initial steps in the thread and run the tests which still runs without any problem.
The tests that are running successfully should not be running as they are dependent on login step.
Can someone help me clarify this doubt?

[image]

Comment: I expect that when the login doesn't happen, the rest of the tests should fail as none of rest of the URLs will load without login at first place.

Comment: Did you tried my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Add as a parent an If Controller for the dependent samplers,

You can easily mark requests and

*Right Click -> Insert Parent -> Logic Controller -> If Controller*

Check that login wasn't failed using condition:

```
 ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}
```

Answer (score 0):

JMeters [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) are **independent**, JMeter doesn't "read" its labels and "think" that "well, login is disabled, I will not run dashboard", it just executes enabled Samplers upside down (or according to the logic controllers)

With regards to this "The tests that are running successfully" statement: how do you know that they're running successfully and doing what they're supposed to be doing?

If you're relying on JMeter as well be informed that JMeter automatically treats all the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers which return [status code below 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) as successful.

Try adding [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved/) to each samplers and introduce explicit checks for the text which each page must contain just as an extra layer of confidence so JMeter would conditionally fail the sampler if it will not find the associated text at the page

Comment: I will try adding Response Assertion and see if that helps. Thanks.